# Google Sheets API Issue: Requested entity was not found even if Sheets ID is 100% Correct (PHP Client)

Tags: php, google-sheets, google-api

Pretty stuck here.
I followed this guy to the dot
https://www.fillup.io/post/read-and-write-google-sheets-from-php/

...except for the ROLE part. I couldn't find the Service Account Actor role as indicated in the guide so chose Role= OWNER instead to make sure everything's enabled.

Oh and I choose to point setAuthConfig to path to my credentials.json file.

Then I made sure I got the correct Sheet ID

> https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/COPIED_THE_CONTENTS_HERE/edit?resourcekey#gid=1691520531

And I have granted EDITOR access to the email account in my credentials.json file

Yet I'm still getting the error

> "errors": [ { "message": "Requested entity was not found.", "domain": "global", "reason": "notFound" } ], "status": "NOT_FOUND" }

[image: Screenshot of my current code]

I searched stack for answers but all I could find were fixes involving

1. the correct sheet ID (which I believe is 100% correct in my project)
2. making sure the App is authenticated or the sheet gives access to my API creds (which I believe I am or else I would get a different error)

I also tried using other sheets, some older sheets, to make sure this isn't a cache/lag thing on server API side, but newp, I'm getting the exact errors.

So at this point, I'm pretty stuck :(

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand about your situation, for example, if the owner of Spreadsheet is the service account or the Spreadsheet is shared with the email of the service account, when the Spreadsheet ID is directly used for `$spreadsheetId` like `$spreadsheetId = '###';`, what result will you obtain? If this was not the direct solution of your issue, I apologize.

Comment: Two quesitons: 1. Are you sure you are using the correct `credentials.json` file with service account credentials. 2.  Does the service account have access to the specified spreadsheet? If not - either share the file with the service account as suggested by Tanaike or use impersonation to make the service account act on behalf of the user who has access to the spreadsheet.

Comment: @ziganotschka 
im pretty sure i got both covered. if #1(creds) are wrong then i would probably get authentication error...  and if #2 (permission) well i've set the service account to OWNER so i dont think it can get any better than that right? or do i have to set it as editor or somethign else? i figured OWNER role is best for testing

Comment: Is the spreadsheet that cannot be found located on a shared drive?